# Jquery select list: show the placeholder when returning to page

Tags: jquery-mobile, placeholder

I'm working on a phonegap project: 1 html page with 3 (data-role) pages.
One of them contains a select-list with a placeholder.

When the user selects a value in the dropdown, navigates away from the page and comes back, the selected value remains visible. 
How can I initialize the list back to the placeholder (without making the placeholder an actual value in the list)?

HTML

```html
<label for="cadeauvoor">Idee voor</label>
<select id="cadeauvoor" name="cadeauvoor">
  <option value="" data-placeholder="true">Kies...</option>
  <option value="Anne">Anne</option>
  <option value="Arno">Arno</option>
  <option value="Christophe">Christophe</option>
  <option value="Dirk">Dirk</option>
</select>
```

JS

```js
function InitNieuweTip() {
  $("#cadeauvoor").val('');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it to either `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page_id', function () {
  $('#cadeauvoor option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
  $('#cadeauvoor').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Where `option:eq(0)` is the first option (*placeholder*) in selectmenu.

Comment: This works! Thank you. I have more elements on my page (input fields, a google map via geolocation...). Is there a way to have the complete page initialized the way it originally was (so all input fields empty for example.) So that I don't have to iniatilize each field separately?

Comment: If that page is the first page in html file, call the below code when clicking back button `$.mobile.changePage('file.html', { reloadPage: true });` @user2764363